# Cannot Sudo or edit sodoer to add user

Tags: server, 20.04

I successfully installed Ubunto Server 20.04 on Raspberry Pi. I added a user, but the user, me, cannot sudo, not edit sudoer file to allow sudo. Was not prompted to add administer at installation.

Comment: The user that was created during installation will have sudo (administrator) privileges.  If you are experiencing a problem running commands and would like our help- you must edit your question and include each command and its output.  Without those details, we can't guess the problem you are experiencing and won't be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by reinstalling Ubuntu server, immediately adding user,$ sudo adduser username, then adding to sudoers file, $ sudo usermod -aG sudo sampleuser before logging out and running as user. Now it works just fine.